# Powershell - Search and output line by line

Tags: powershell, output

UPDATE

I have got a log file of 1000 lines containing some reference.

```
Time Reference Date of start Date of end
12:00 AT001 13 November 2011 15 November 2011
13:00 AT038 15 December 2012 17 December 2012
14:00 AT076 17 January 2013 19 January 2013
```

$ref1 = AT038

Basically, I want to parse the log file and have an output (line by line) for $ref1 such as :

```
Time : 13h
Reference : AT038
Date of start : 15 December 2012
Date of end : 17 December 2012
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Edited my answer to fit with your new infos

Comment: This isn't a question, its a request to have someone else do the work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$ref1 = "AT038"
$csv = Import-Csv .\myfile.txt -Delimiter ' '#Import file as CSV with space as delimiter
$csv | ? { $_.reference -EQ $ref1 } | FL #Piping each line of CSV to where-object cmdlet,  filtering only line where value of column reference is equal to $ref1 variable value. Piping the result of the filtering to file-list to have output as requested in OP.
```

Code added after requisite are changed in OP:

```
$ref1 = "AT038"
$txt = gc .\myfile.txt
$txt2 = $txt | % { $b = $_ -split ' '; "$($b[0]) $($b[1]) $($b[2])_$($b[3])_$($b[4]) $($b[5])_$($b[6])_$($b[7])" }
$csv = convertfrom-csv -InputObject $txt2 -Delimiter ' ' 
$csv | ? { $_.reference -EQ $ref1 } | FL
```

Comment: some explanation would help this answer

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Get-Content SourceFileName.txt | 
% { ($_ -Replace '(\d{2}):\d{2} (\w{2}\d{3})', 'Time : $1h|Reference : $2').Split('|')} |
Out-File TargetFileName.txt
```

Comment: Sorry guys I forgot to tell you that I have got more columns in my log, I just updated my first post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my revised version:

```
$regex = '(\d{2}):\d{2} (\w{2}\d{3}) (\d{2} \b\w+\b \d{4}) (\d{2} \b\w+\b \d{4})'
$replace = 'Time : $1h|Reference : $2|Date of start : $3|Date of end : $4'
Get-Content SourceFileName.txt | 
% { ($_ -Replace $regex, $replace).Split('|')} |
Out-File TargetFileName.txt
```